# flexbox позиционирование и разная высота элементов

Tags: css

Можно ли как-то реализовать вот такую структуру на flexbox?
https://clip2net.com/clip/m0/ed452-clip-5kb.png?nocache=1
Пытаюсь вот так:

```
<style>
    .test {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
        .test div {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
</style>
```

Но создаётся пустое пространство https://clip2net.com/clip/m0/673dc-clip-6kb.png?nocache=1
Всем спасибо

Comment: Ну или как можно ещё сделать такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так вот запросто это делается на гридах:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.item {
  background: tomato;
}

.item:first-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, но ТС спросил о другом-то. Можно ли это выполнить на флексах? :)

Comment: Он спросил как ещё можно сделать такое, я показал самые легкий вариант без дополнительных контейнеров(если делать на флексах).

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил его комментария. )) Обычно, такие нюансы описываются в теле вопроса.